# How we decide sample rate and number of samples while doing discrete Fourier transform

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I solved a differential equation numerically and I want to find the frequencies present in the solution but I am not able to figure out sample rate/frequency and no. of samples that I should take.can anyone help me? I am new in this field. I have done this in the following way,

```
Suppose N is no. of sampled data, then
sampling interval(t0)=period of function/N
sampling freq (f)=1/t0
and the highest freq that DFT will detect(Nyquist freq)=1/(2*t0)
```

Correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Are sure you know the period of the function. I guess it is unknown.

Comment: @ Neeks the solution that I got from differential equation is periodic with period 2 but this function contains number of frequencies that I want to identify

Comment: I posted this question as unregistered member so I am not able to write a comment.
sorry for inconvenience.
@Neeks I think you are doing the same thing except plotting part.
Jason can you please explain your program and if possible can you please let me know what I have done wrong.

Comment: You need to [merge the accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist), easy to do.  And not sure if this is the place for a discussion of mathematica code (based on the downvotes my answer received).  But I found [this page](https://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/washburn/Teaching/Class%20Files/NQO/Tutorials/Tutorial8_FFT.pdf) useful.  Essentially what I'm doing is creating a timeseries where I know the frequency exactly, so that I can make sure my FFT setup puts the peak in exactly the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here we go! You need not worry about the period of the data as DFT will retrieve reflect it in the result. Take the time series data (that is your solution vector, denoting it by $\mathbf{x}$). I assume the data points are uniformly spaced apart in time. Now, considering the whole data denotes $T$ secs and you have $N$ data points, then sampling interval is $T_s = T/N$, and sampling rate is $F_s=1/T_s$. Take a DFT of $\mathbf{x}$. Here you need to take care of NFFT, that is what point DFT to take? To begin, take $NFFT = 2^{\log_2(length(\mathbf{x}))}$. Let $\mathbf{X}$ denote the obtained DFT. Now, plot magnitude of $\mathbf{X}$, and the x-axis of the plot will be $f=[0:1:NFFT]/NFFT*F_s$. Remember there will be a symmetry around NFFT/2 for real signals.
Hope the above helps!

Answer (score 0):

The selection of duration and sample rate depends on the differential equation, and may require a finite error bound, in case the solution is some sort of bounded infinite series (harmonic, etc.), or not possible (if the solution enters a pole or an extreme chaotic regime).  Trial and error measured against total energy may be one possibility.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I would search this exact questions, I find a lot of answers just giving the definition of the Fourier transform, but for me, I like a practical utility I can use that I can use.  You asked this over in the Mathematica SE, and I dug up my FFT functions that I use when I want to do this.  This function will display the time and frequency ranges, given the only two open parameters, the number of time points and the time interval:

```
fourierparameters[num_, dt_] := 
 Module[{makeTable, 
   disp, δω, ωstep, ωrange},
  disp[x_?StringQ] := Style[x, FontFamily -> Times, 13];
  makeTable[m_?MatrixQ] := 
   DisplayForm[
    GridBox[Map[ToBoxes, m, {2}], ColumnLines -> True, 
     RowLines -> True, GridFrame -> True, 
     ColumnAlignments -> {Center, "."}]];
  δω := 2 π/(num dt);
  timevalues := 
   RotateLeft[Table[t, {t, -dt num/2 + dt, num/2 dt, dt}], 
    num/2 - 1];
  fftshift[flist_] := Chop[RotateRight[flist, num/2 - 1]];
  ωstep := δω(*/cf cm1*);
  ωrange := {-num/2 + 1, num/2} δω;
  freqvalues := 
   Table[w, {w, ωrange[[1]], ωrange[[-1]], \
ωstep}];

  makeTable[{{disp["Number of sample points"], 
     num}, {disp["δt "], dt}, {disp["time range (fs)"], 
     PlusMinus[num dt/2]}, {disp[
      "δω "], ωstep}, {disp[
      "frequency range "], PlusMinus[num ωstep/2]}}]
  ];
```

Then call the function, supplying the number of sample points and the timestep:

```
fourierparameters[2^12, .2]
```

[image]

This defines the list `timevalues` and `freqvalues`.  Next I like to check it by making sure that it plots the frequency exactly where I put it in a simple oscillating function.

```
ν = 4.7;
timelist = Table[UnitStep[t] Exp[-I ν t - .01 t], {t, timevalues}];
freqlist = Fourier[timelist];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{freqvalues, Re@fftshift@freqlist}], 
 PlotRange -> {{ν - .5, ν + .5}, All}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

[image]